# Limitation on Ne10 ARM library maximum length fft

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, arm, fft

I'm computing the Fourier transform of a 2^18 samples vector using the FFT included in Ne10 ARM library and it doesn't seem to work. It produces a Sigsev error on the Android Studio. The funny thing is that a 512 samples FFT works well. My questions are:

1. Is there a limitation on the maximum amount of samples I can compute the fft on with this library?:

I'm using:

```
fftPlan = ne10_fft_alloc_c2c_float32_neon(fftSize);
fftIn = (ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t*)NE10_MALLOC (fftSize * sizeof (ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t));
fftOut = (ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t*)NE10_MALLOC (fftSize * sizeof (ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t));
```

2. Are these memory allocating functions thread safe? (I've tested and they seem to)
3. Leaving out their own FFT benchmark comparisons. Is there any other 3rd party site where I can compare its performance with fftw?
4. The library produces a "text relocations warning" when I use NDK10e for building the native shared library loaded from my android app, which when using ndk13 produces the following error :

   D:/AndroidDevelop/android-ndk-r13/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: warning: shared library text segment is not shareable

   D:/AndroidDevelop/android-ndk-r13/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: treating warnings as errors clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: WHat happens when the sample size is greater than 512? You never really stated the problem. What does `errno` return? Are you running into an `ENOMEM`? Many Android phones and other gadgets have little in the way of RAM. i would not be surprised of the device only has 512 MB.

Comment: `NE10_MALLOC()` and `ne10_fft_alloc_c2c_float32_neon()` can fail if there is not enough memory available. In these cases, these functions return `NULL`. Can you test it by adding `if(fftPlan==NULL || fftIn==NULL || fftOut==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}`?